# Number of different orders of $\{a_1,\cdots,a_7\}$ where $a_{k+1}-a_k\neq2$ for $a_k=1,2,\cdots7$ and $1\leq k\leq 6$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Recently, I have found this problem:

> In how many ways can we order the sequence $1,2,3,\cdots,7$ in the set $\mathcal{K}=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_7\}$ such that $a_{k+1}-a_k\neq2$ for $1\leq k\leq 6$?

I have tried to approach this problem by recursion, but I can't figure out a general formula. In fact, when $a_1=7$ we can use all possible numers $1,2,\cdots6$, but when we set $a_1=1$ then we can't use all the numbers $2,3,\cdots,7$ because $3$ is not acceptable. So, I am stuck. Canto someone help me? Any idea?

Comment: What's wrong with $1765432$?  It starts with $1$ and satisfies $a_{k+1} - a_k \neq 2$ right?

Comment: @antkam: nothing, why?

Comment: haha, sorry, i must have misunderstood you.  you said "when we set $a_1 = 1$ then we can't use all the numbers $2,3,4,5,6,7$" -- i thought you meant there is no way to arrange $234567$ in any order (to satisfy the criterion), but in fact you meant you cannot use $234567$ _in that order_, right?  :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $N_m(n)$ count the ways you can arrange the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ so that there are exactly $m$ "bad pairs," i.e., adjacent numbers with $a_{k+1}-a_k=2$. We have the following recursion:

$$N_m(n+1)=(m+1)N_{m+1}(n)+(n-m)N_m(n)+N_{m-1}(n)$$

That is, when you insert the next number, $n+1$, into a permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, you wind up with $m$ bad pairs in one of three ways: if the placement of $n+1$ busts up one of $m+1$ existing bad pairs; if it goes into one of the $n-m$ positions that neither busts up a bad pair nor creates a new bad pair (by going after the number $n-1$); or if it adds a new bad pair to $m-1$ existing ones by going after the number $n-1$.

Suppressing values that are obviously $0$, we see that $N_0(1)=1$ and $N_0(2)=2$, followed by

$$\begin{align}
N_0(3)&=2N_0(2)=4\\
N_1(3)&=N_1(2)=2\qquad\text{(note }2+4=6=3!)\\
\\
N_0(4)&=N_1(3)+3N_0(3)=2+3\cdot4=14\\
N_1(4)&=2N_1(3)+N_0(3)=2\cdot2+4=8\\
N_2(4)&=N_1(3)=2\qquad\text{(note }2+8+14=24=4!)\\\\
N_0(5)&=N_1(4)+4N_0(4)=8+4\cdot14=64\\
N_1(5)&=2N_2(4)+3N_1(4)+N_0(4)=2\cdot2+3\cdot8+14=42\\
N_2(5)&=2N_2(4)+N_1(4)=2\cdot2+8=12\\
N_3(5)&=N_2(4)=2\qquad\text{(note }2+12+42+64=120=5!)\\\\
N_0(6)&=N_1(5)+5N_0(5)=42+5\cdot64=362\\
N_1(6)&=2N_2(5)+4N_1(5)+N_0(5)=2\cdot12+4\cdot42+64=256\\
N_2(6)&=3N_3(5)+3N_2(5)+N_1(5)=3\cdot2+3\cdot12+42=84\\
N_3(6)&=2N_3(5)+N_2(5)=2\cdot2+12=16\\
N_4(6)&=N_3(5)=2\qquad\text{(note }2+16+84+256+362=720=6!)\\\\
N_0(7)&=N_1(6)+6N_0(6)=256+6\cdot362=2428
\end{align}$$

and that's our answer, $2428$.

Remarks:

In order to arrive at the answer for $N_0(7)$, it was not necessary to compute $N_4(6)$, $N_3(6)$, $N_2(6)$, or $N_3(5)$. I included them partly for the heck of it, but mainly to allow for the sanity check that $\sum_kN_k(n)=n!$, to help avoid making embarrassing arithmetic mistakes.

Searching OEIS for the sequence $2,4,14,64,362,2428,\ldots$ turns up [A055790](https://oeis.org/A055790), which suggests, in the indexing we're using here, a nice two-term recursion:

$$N_0(n+1)=nN_0(n)+(n-2)N_0(n-1)$$

Searching OEIS for $2,8,42,256,\ldots$ turns up [A018934](https://oeis.org/A018934), which suggests

$$N_1(n+1)=(n-1)N_0(n)$$

Indeed, this together with the recursion $N_0(n+1)=N_1(n)+nN_0(n)$ gives the two-term recursion for $N_0$. The equation $N_1(n+1)=(n-1)N_0(n)$ seems simple enough that there ought to be a simple direct proof of it, but for some reason I can't think of one. I would welcome an answer giving a proof that would render this answer superfluous.

Comment: Very interesting... The $N_1(n+1) = (n-1) N_0(n)$ recursion would seem to suggest that, among the $N_1(n+1)$ permutations with a single bad pair, the bad pair is equally likely to be any of the $(n-1)$ values.  But that kind of symmetry is not obvious to me due to boundary effects...